# Variables in php(html input)

Tags: php, html

How would you take a input split by spaces in html and store it as separate variables in php? Ex user types "red yellow green".the code creates three variables.

Comment: I would submit the string as a whole to php. Be it using GET or POST it doesn't matter and then split the string using `$array = explode($string, ' ')`

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_POST` or `$_GET` then you can use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) function

```
$string = 'red yellow green';

// explode with space delimiter then set variables via list
list($color1, $color2, $color3) = explode(' ', $string);

echo $color1; // red
echo $color2; // yellow
echo $color3; // green
```

Assuming you know how many separate strings there will be. Otherwise, you need to set each variable on exploded string one by one or via `foreach`